# Powershell use one liner instead of 3 lines

Tags: powershell, split

I have data file

```
$data=gc c:\blabla.cfg
```

inside it i have all kind of lines, i want to extract the data, example, in the file I have :

```
SMTP_SERVER = smtp.bla.local
```

so if i want to create variable inside the script for example : $smtp which have this information, this is how i do it:

```
$tmp = $data | Select-string SMTP_SERVER
$smtp=($tmp -split ' ')[2]
```

It may look kind of dumb its just that i have lots of configuration to take from the file and id like to take it in one liners with pipe,
if i do this:

```
$smtp = $data | Select-String SMTP_SERVER | $_.Split(' ')[2]
```

I'm getting an error saying Expression are only allowed as the first element of pipeline

Comment: What's the second closing parenthesis for?

Comment: Mistake, Edited, problem of cours still remains

Comment: You may take a look at the cmdlet [ConvertFrom-StringData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-stringdata?view=powershell-7.1). It's a kind of INI file converter. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `ForEach-Object`

```
Select-String -Path "c:\blabla.cfg" -SimpleMatch "SMTP_SERVER" | ForEach-Object { $_.ToString().Split(' ')[2] }
```